# Does Cantors Theorem imply one can never build nested closed sets with empty intersection?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Granted, I know Cantors Theorem says that it has to be nonempty, but what if we have some Cauchy sequence that is not complete? I was thinking it would be possible then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible in an incomplete metric space.  Take, for example the rationals with the usual metric.  Can you come up with a decreasing sequence of balls, whose intersection should be $\{\sqrt{2}\;\}$, but is instead empty since $2$ has no square-root?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this to me. I really appreciate it. Now that I see the example, it really makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Cantor's theorem, as you have stated it, is an *equivalence*, an "if and only if" theorem. Thus, there are really two statements here:

1. If $(X,d)$ is complete, then every descending chain of closed balls with radii tending to $0$ has nonempty intersection.
2. If $(X,d)$ is not complete, then there exists at least one descending chain of closed balls with radii tending to $0$ with empty intersection.

Thus, by statement 2, if you want to find an example of a decreasing chain of balls with radii tending to $0$ that has empty intersection, you can always find one in a non-complete space. For example, if $X = \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\{0\}$, then the (closed) balls $(0,1/n]$ for $n\geq 1$ have empty intersection.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this to me. I really appreciate it. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be a bit more precise about the assumptions you're making. A 'Cauchy sequence that is not complete' doesn't make much sense. You should also use the word compact, as a nested sequence of closed sets can indeed have empty intersection:
Let $$A_n = [n,\infty).$$ Then $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset ...$, so the $A_n$s are nested -- but *not* compact. Indeed,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset.$$

Comment: The poster did say "closed balls whose radii tend to zero."  Your example does not deal with closed balls, and the length of your sets doesn't tend to zero.

Comment: @SpamIAm This is one of those cases where the title disagrees with the body of the question, and snarski chose to answer the question in the title, which speaks of **nested closed sets**. Is there an official policy against answering the title in such cases?

Comment: @bof I speak only for myself, but I try to respond to the full question, not just the title.  Moreover, this answer chides the OP be more precise with his assumptions, when those assumptions are explicitly spelled out in the question.  I do agree that the title could be more descriptive.  Why don't you suggest modifying the title to the OP in a comment?

Comment: @SpamIAm, I agree with you. I started thinking about the question, started writing a comment, and then figured it might be useful to have this counterexample in mind, not necessarily intending to answer the question. To be fair, it wasn't clear to me what the poster wanted.